# Api validation in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, json, laravel, api, validation

Hi guys I'm working on API but I need to validate some data at backend, in this case, we only need a postman to send parameters and headers.

All is working fine now but I need more useful data in each request, Laravel has by default a Validator [Form Request Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation), but I don´t know how to use at API side.

I need to send the error message in JSON to Postman.

I found two options, one, make validations into a controller but seems to much code and the other make a ***php artisan make:request StoreObjectPost*** and then import the request into the controller and change the request of the store method, which one do you recommend, Ty!

Answer (score 4):

You could instantiate the validator yourself like this:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'name' => 'min:5'
]);

// then, if it fails, return the error messages in JSON format
if ($validator->fails()) {    
    return response()->json($validator->messages(), 200);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$PostData = Input::all();
$Validator = Validator::make(array(
     'name' => $PostData['name']
      ), array(
      'name' => 'required'
));
if ($Validator->fails()) { //if validator is failed
   return false;
} else {
      // do some thing here
}
```

Hope this may help you

Answer (score 1):

You should override `response(array $errors)` method of `FormRequest`.

```
public function response(array $errors)
{
    //Format your error message

    if ($this->expectsJson()) {
        return new JsonResponse($errors, 422);
    }

    return $this->redirector->to($this->getRedirectUrl())
                                    ->withInput($this->except($this->dontFlash))
                                    ->withErrors($errors, $this->errorBag);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the second option. We will be able to keep our controller clean that way, even when we use many validations for the data or using custom error message in the validation